# BottomNavigationView. Navigation to destination with deeplink cause to add destination fragment also in first tab

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnav, android-deep-link

Let's say we have a bottom navigation view with 4 tabs, we have a deeplink for a fragment of 4 tab, so when navigating from this deeplink to 4 tab - it works as it should, but when after that manually select the first tab, a fragment of 4 tab is added also in the first tab.

1. i have a nav graph with 4 fragments
2. in on create of my activity i set the bottom view with nav controller

   ```
               navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as? NavHostFragment
               navController = navHostFragment?.navController
               navController?.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_unauth_state)
               navView.inflateMenu(getBottomNavViewMenu())
               navController?.let {
                   navView.setupWithNavController(it)
               }
   ```
3. in manifest for this activity i added `<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_unauth_state" />`
4. in nav_unauth_state for frgament i set the deeplink

```
            android:id="@+id/deepLink2"
            app:uri="https://<my_secret_url>/{action}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

i solved it my self with this solution

```
navView.setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
    val builder = NavOptions.Builder().setLaunchSingleTop(true).setRestoreState(false)
    val graph = navController?.currentDestination?.parent
    val destination = graph?.findNode(menuItem.itemId)
    if (menuItem.order and Menu.CATEGORY_SECONDARY == 0) {
        navController?.graph?.findStartDestination()?.id?.let {
            builder.setPopUpTo(
                it,
                inclusive = false,
                saveState = true
            )
        }
    }
    val options = builder.build()
    destination?.id?.let { id -> navController.navigate(id, null, options) }
    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
}
```

Comment: The problem was in setRestoreState(true) , set to setRestoreState(false and works

Comment: Thanks for this answer it helped me. But it also removes the saved back stack functionality. I hope someone is able to find a solution that keeps the saved back stack